# Preprocessing data in HighCharts JS in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, charts, highcharts

I'm creating a bar chart in ASP.NET 2.0 using [HighCharts JS](http://www.highcharts.com/).

here's how the chart can be do in javascript:

```
$(function () { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});​
```

i have this in c# code-behind:

```
public string[] Names = new string[] { "Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};
public string[] Data = new  string[] { "[1,0,4]", "[5,7,3]", "[2,3,4]"};
```

How can I used this string[] Names and Data in javascript to change the value of the chart?

Please help I'm stuck in it. :( Thanks!

**--EDIT for ARISTOS--**

I tried your answer but that doesn't work. Base on your answer this javascript will be the same with what you do. check this:

```
$(function () { 
    var seriesTest = "{ name: 'Jane', data: [1, 0, 4] }, { name: 'John', data: [5, 7, 3] }";

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [seriesTest]
    });
});​
```

I tried this already but this not work because I think series.data only accepts integer inside its bracket ([]).

I already check DotNet.HighCharts as suggested by KingCronus but this can't be use in asp.net 2.0 framework. :(

Comment: Not strictly an answer to your question, but have you considered using a helper library? http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/

Comment: @KingCronus your comment gives me idea but I wonder if this can be use in asp.net 2.0? Because I am creating a page in a sharepoint and sharepoint only accepts asp.net 2.0 page.

Comment: Try to change your edit to proper JSON: `var seriesTest = '[{ "name": "Jane", "data": [1, 0, 4] }, { "name": "John", "data": [5, 7, 3] }]';`. And then: `series: JSON.parse(seriesTest)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what my solution for my problem, in case there would someone need this also.

Here's the JS function:

```
function LoadChart() {
    var Names = <%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.Names %>;
    var Data =  <%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.Data %>;

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: Names[0],
            data: [Data[0]]
        }]
    };

    for (var i=1; i<Names.Length; i++)
    {
        options.series.push({
            name: Names[i],
            data: [Data[i]]
        });
    }
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}
```

Here's some part of the code behind:

```
public JavaScriptSerializer javaSerial = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
public string[] Names = new string[] { "Jane", "John", "Mike" };
public string[] Data = new string[] { "1,2,3", "2,4,6", "3,6,9" }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the most simple form, you just need to render them on the correct format.
Here is a simple example that maybe need a few tweeks...

Run this on code behind, maybe on PageLoad

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
 sb.AppendFormat("{3}{{name: '{0}',data: {1} }}", 
      Names[i], Data[i], 
       i>0 ? "," : "" // this is render the comma "," after the first line
  );    

ScriptData.Text = sb.ToString();
```

And place them on the script on the page using a Literal control

```
$(function () { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [
        <asp:Literan id="ScriptData" Runat="server" EnableViewState="off" />
        ]
    });
});?
```